# Sending email with gmail smtp with codeigniter email library

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

```
<?php
class Email extends Controller {

    function Email()
    {
        parent::Controller();   
        $this->load->library('email');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_port']    = '465';
        $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
        $config['smtp_user']    = 'mygmail@gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_pass']    = '*******';
        $config['charset']    = 'utf-8';
        $config['newline']    = "\r\n";
        $config['mailtype'] = 'text'; // or html
        $config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not      

        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->from('mygmail@gmail.com', 'myname');
        $this->email->to('target@gmail.com'); 

        $this->email->subject('Email Test');
        $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  

        $this->email->send();

        echo $this->email->print_debugger();

        $this->load->view('email_view');
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection timed out)
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1641
```

Using `PORT 25/587`

I got this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:func(119):reason(252)
Filename: libraries/Email.php
Line Number: 1641
```

I don't want to use phpmailer now. (Actually I have tried to use phpmailer, but I failed).

How do I solve this problem guys?

Comment: `$config['validation'] = TRUE` is wrong, the index key is **validate** so use `$config['validate'] = TRUE`

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

// Set to, from, message, etc.

$result = $this->email->send();
```

From the [CodeIgniter Forums](http://web.archive.org/web/20091027211607/http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/132443/)

Comment: +1, Notice all Array elements are enclosed in single quotes, and only parameters of `$this->email->set_newline` is enclosed in double quotes. this is very important or else it does not work.

Comment: that is because in PHP(and a few other languages) `\n` only means new line if it is in double quotes. In single quotes it means the literal characters \n.

Comment: The solution was,thnx: for the $this->email->set_newline("\r\n")

Comment: @NaveenKumar still not able to send the email. not getting any response in `$result = $this->email->send();`

Comment: @ThorpeObazee  Sir Can we Add some more configuration in the mail config file. like, $config['subjectEnquiry'] => "Enquiry Email";   or $config['subjectSuccess'] => "successfully added the data";

Comment: I have found the article which describe how to send emails in a CodeIgniter application using SMTP and using the well known and maintained email sending class. https://www.cloudways.com/blog/send-email-codeigniter-smtp/

Comment: I have found the article which demonstrate how to send emails in a CodeIgniter application using SMTP. https://www.cloudways.com/blog/send-email-codeigniter-smtp/

Comment: please someone tell me ,  in email library which code should i use . i don't have email library how can i get email library . i am new in CI

Comment: i used same code...but in my mail box ..got email that "Sign-in attempt was blocked" what more settings is needed ? my IMAP is enabled already

Comment: The important point is the use of `$CI->email->set_newline("\r\n");` line. Other wise no issue of declaring and initializing the `$config` array. Obviously we should enable `extension=php_openssl.dll`

Comment: Using the above works, but if I change **'charset' => 'utf-8'** the message is not delivered.  I'm using CodeIgniter 3.1.9 hosted on GoDaddy.  I've read that Gmail changes all messages to utf-8 anyway.  Any idea why 'utf-8' would fail to get delivered?

Answer (score 20):

According to the CI docs ([CodeIgniter Email Library](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html))...

> If you prefer not to set preferences using the above method, you can
>   instead put them into a config file. Simply create a new file called
>   the email.php, add the $config array in that file. Then save the file
>   at config/email.php and it will be used automatically. You will NOT
>   need to use the $this->email->initialize() function if you save your
>   preferences in a config file.

I was able to get this to work by putting all the settings into **application/config/email.php**.

```
$config['useragent'] = 'CodeIgniter';
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
//$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'YOUREMAILHERE@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'YOURPASSWORDHERE';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465; 
$config['smtp_timeout'] = 5;
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['wrapchars'] = 76;
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['validate'] = FALSE;
$config['priority'] = 3;
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['bcc_batch_mode'] = FALSE;
$config['bcc_batch_size'] = 200;
```

Then, in one of the controller methods I have something like:

```
$this->load->library('email'); // Note: no $config param needed
$this->email->from('YOUREMAILHERE@gmail.com', 'YOUREMAILHERE@gmail.com');
$this->email->to('SOMEEMAILHERE@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('Test email from CI and Gmail');
$this->email->message('This is a test.');
$this->email->send();
```

Also, as Cerebro wrote, I had to uncomment out this line in my php.ini file and restart PHP:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: will you  provide me email library code , every time i saw $this->load->library('email') but i dont have email libraery what can i do ?? please sir give me a way i am newer in CI & coding  . thanks you :)

Comment: This is working to the date.

Answer (score 19):

You need to enable SSL in your PHP config. Load up `php.ini` and find a line with the following:

`;extension=php_openssl.dll`

Uncomment it. :D

(by removing the semicolon from the statement)

`extension=php_openssl.dll`

Comment: This is only for Windows Servers.  Use phpinfo() to see if you have the proper sockets available and if openssl is on your server.

Answer (score 7):

Change it to the following:

```
$ci = get_instance();
$ci->load->library('email');
$config['protocol'] = "smtp";
$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$config['smtp_port'] = "465";
$config['smtp_user'] = "blablabla@gmail.com"; 
$config['smtp_pass'] = "yourpassword";
$config['charset'] = "utf-8";
$config['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";

$ci->email->initialize($config);

$ci->email->from('blablabla@gmail.com', 'Blabla');
$list = array('xxx@gmail.com');
$ci->email->to($list);
$this->email->reply_to('my-email@gmail.com', 'Explendid Videos');
$ci->email->subject('This is an email test');
$ci->email->message('It is working. Great!');
$ci->email->send();
```

Answer (score 5):

send html email via codeiginater

```
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->load->library('parser');



    $this->email->clear();
    $config['mailtype'] = "html";
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from('email@example.com', 'Website');
    $list = array('xxxxxxxx@archmage.lk', 'xxxxx@gmail.com');
    $this->email->to($list);
    $data = array();
    $htmlMessage = $this->parser->parse('messages/email', $data, true);
    $this->email->subject('This is an email test');
    $this->email->message($htmlMessage);



    if ($this->email->send()) {
        echo 'Your email was sent, thanks chamil.';
    } else {
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option I have working, in a linux server with Postfix:

First, configure CI email to use your server's email system: eg, in `email.php`, for example

```
# alias to postfix in a typical Postfix server
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail'; 
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
```

Then configure your postfix to relay the mail to google (perhaps depending on the sender address). You'll probably need to put you user-password settings in `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`
[(docs)](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl_sender)

This is much simpler (and less fragmente) if you have a linux box, already configured to send some/all of its outgoing emails to Google.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your hosting server and email server are located at same place and you don't need to go for smtp authentication. Just keep every thing default like:

```
$config = array(        
    'protocol' => '',
    'smtp_host' => '',
    'smtp_port' => '',
    'smtp_user' => 'yourname@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => '**********'
    );
```

or

```
$config['protocol'] = '';
$config['smtp_host'] = '';
$config['smtp_port'] = ;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'yourname@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
```

it works for me.

Comment: Do not work for me without


$config['crlf'] = "\r\n"; 
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";

Answer (score 1):

It can be this:

> If you are using cpanel for your website smtp restrictions are problem
>   and cause this error. SMTP Restrictions

[Error while sending an email with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694351/error-while-sending-an-email-with-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

There  is very simple answer to this . and the only solution that worked at the en was this configuration ..i only had to chnage the port to 587 and overwrite the codeignitor default "Email.php"

```
$config = array( 'protocol' => 'smtp', 'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com', 'smtp_port' => 587, 'smtp_user' => 'admin@cafeadmin.com.au', 'smtp_pass' => '1800@Footscray123!' );$this->load->library('email', $config);$this->email->initialize($config);
```