# Issues with Google SMTP and CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, smtp, gmail

I have seen a lot of other people had this issue.

I have setup an email form using the Google Mail server to send the email. This worked on my local machine, but once i put it on the server i get this error

```
The following SMTP error was encountered: 110 Connection timed out
Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error:
Unable to send data: MAIL FROM:

from: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: RCPT TO:

to: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: DATA

data: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: User-Agent: CodeIgniter Date: Thu, 2 Feb 2012 14:24:43 +0000
```

Here is the setup i have in CI

```
$config = array (
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_user' => 'emial',
    'smtp_pass' => 'password',
    'smtp_port' => '465',
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'charset'  => 'utf-8',
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE
);
```

I have tried using both port465 and 587, and both ssl://smtp.googlemail.com and tls://smtp.googlemail.com

Any help getting this working would be great.

Comment: You may want to try the solution [posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library).

Comment: Thanks, but that is what i have, i don't have an issue with fsockopen issue, it something to do with the port possibly.

Comment: I'm unsure how much it matters, but I noticed that the `charset` is different.

Comment: Hi Colin, seems to work if i remove the 'html' it will only send text. Not sure why, but it works...

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line to your email config:

```
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

Comment: Thanks @WebNovice will note that!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better if you do not change core files of framework.

In my case

```
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

didn't work but adding

```
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

to the method sending an email somehow did the job.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem and I was able to send as `text` by changing `$newline` in `system/libraries/Email.php` to `\r\n`

Comment: Thanks @ow3n will note that!