# Codeigniter emails not being received by gmail

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have an app where i'm sending emails on certain events, but when i used my gmail account, i never receive the emails and they are not in my spam folder. When i send them to my work email, i receive them instantaneously.

What do i need to do to get the emails through to google?

I'm using the standard codeigniter email configs (which i think uses sendmail).

I'm using google apps for business and i have the MX records setup that google provides.

Do i need anything else? Also, i'm using subdomains in my app, does that affect what i may need to setup?

[image]
[image]

**EDIT**

When i use smtp like this example [Sending email with gmail smtp with codeigniter email library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library), the page never seems to come back. It eventually just timesout.

Comment: Are the mail messages received in other mail clients?

Comment: I receive them at my work email so yes.

Comment: are you trying from your localhost or from a web domain?

Comment: can you provide your php.ini email settings and your sending code snippet?

Comment: You might have a firewall issue where outgoing communications to SMTP port is closed, I've had something similar to this before (if you're on localhost & your firewall isn't blocking it then your ISP might be blocking it). as you haven't provided much information nor code then I am assuming you're on localhost so you might want to try using a FREE VPN service to test it with if it works then that's it for now until you upload it somewhere.

Comment: I'm not on localhost. I'm on my VPS.

Comment: Have you checked your firewall "iptables" to make sure you're not blocking ports? port 465 would be closed by default on many managed VPS providers as they mostly leave port 25, 143 open instead.

Comment: I have not checked that. Is that available in cpanel?

Comment: If you're using CSF you might check it in WHM using a root account it's called "Configserver Security & Firewall" if you're using APF you'll have to check it through command line also using a root account, Or you may not be using either of those products so you'll have to check it through command line "SSH" by directly checking iptables output but most likely you have CSF installed as it's very popular for customers using cPanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only plausible explanation for this behaviour is a SPF Check failure. SPF or Sender Policy Framework is a new technology that allows easy detection of spam. Gmail honours SPF unless you manually mark those emails as not spam. Regardless of this, if you have received emails on another address then they **must** have reached Gmail too. Check your spam thoroughly, as Gmail does not discard emails even on very high spam suspicion rather they end up in the Spam folder.

You can set up a SPF that allows your webserver to send emails which will result in Gmail accepting emails sent by your webserver as authentic. See http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-set-up-and-create-sender-policy-framework-spf-domain-dns-txt-record-with-wizard/ and a [wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/) from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably see, that at some point in the future, you'll get them all appearing in Gmail. Google is most likely seeing if the sender is spam, and holding those messages. I've experienced that before setting up dev servers. I would suggest using a transactional email service, like Mandrill or SendGrid. You'll find you get a lot of info from those services that you forgo if you simply send an email through PHP.

Answer (score 0):

**The Filter Theory** The other possibility is that the poster has a filter set up on their GMail account that is filtering out the emails.

I would make sure that you are sending the required header information as well.  Have you tried registering a new gmail account and sending it to that user?

Comment: Three of us have had our gmail accounts not receive the emails.