# sending email to gmail in php codeigniter

Tags: php, email, sendmail.exe

I have to send email to gamil for registration of account in my website. I am using wamp ,win 7, codeigniter. And sending mail through sendmail. I have made all required changes i.e

in php.ini

```
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = myemail@gmail.com
sendmail_path ="C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

And in sendmail.ini

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
auth_username=myemail@gmail.com
auth_password=mypassword
```

But it shows this error instead of sending email.

**Message: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
Filename: libraries/Email.php**

It is still giving error on port 25 but i am using port 465. What could be the possible reason of this? What I am doing wrong? 
Any help.

Comment: you dont have to use "sendmail" program. Reset the php.ini to previous and simply use codeigniter to send the mail; follow instructions in http://stackoverflow.com/a/1622996. No extra config on localhost server required if you're using codeigniter (codeigniter already has an inbuilt php mailer library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made those changes in `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\php.ini` instead of `C:\wamp\bin\php\php.ini`. And it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to restart your server.

edit
I found [this thread](http://drupal.org/node/341969) with soulution:

```
Add the following code to the top of your email script if your mail script continues to fail.


// Please specify your Mail Server - Example: mail.yourdomain.com.
ini_set("SMTP","mail.YourDomain.com");

// Please specify an SMTP Number 25 and 8889 are valid SMTP Ports.
ini_set("smtp_port","25");

// Please specify the return address to use
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'ValidEmailAccount@YourDomain.com');
```

Comment: @ Daniel, These are same steps as i have made changes in php.ini file.

Comment: I know but the author of that thread said that he also had correct configuration in his php.ini - "However, my php.ini is configured correctly". Have a nice day.

Comment: Where do I put these lines? In my php mailsending method or some where else?

Comment: I would first try to put these lines above line where you use mail() function which gives you an error.