# smtp Error in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I am trying to send a password reset link to user using the smtp in codeigniter with following configurations

```
$config = Array('protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'my-host',
                'smtp_user' => 'user',
                'smtp_port' =>25,
                'smtp_pass' => '********',
                '_smtp_auth'=>TRUE,
                'mailtype'  => 'text', 
                'charset'=> 'iso-8859-1'
               );


            $this->load->library('email',$config);
            $this->email->to($address);
            $this->email->from($from);
            $this->email->subject($subject);
            $this->email->message($message);
            $res=$this->email->send();
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

but following error are print by debugger.I am not getting what the actual problem is.

```
220-vps.hostjinniwebhosting.com ESMTP Exim 4.80.1 #2 Fri, 13 Sep 2013 09:48:37 +0530 
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
220 and/or bulk e-mail.
<br /><pre>hello: 250-vps.hostjinniwebhosting.com Hello tv100.info [66.225.213.151]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP
</pre><pre>from: 250 OK
</pre><pre>to: 501 <>: missing or malformed local part
</pre>The following SMTP error was encountered: 501 <>: missing or malformed local part
<br /><pre>data: 503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:
503-501 <>: missing or malformed local part
503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA
</pre>The following SMTP error was encountered: 503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:
503-501 <>: missing or malformed local part
503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA
<br />500 unrecognized command
<br />The following SMTP error was encountered: 500 unrecognized command
<br />Unable to send email using PHP SMTP.  Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.<br /><pre>User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Thu, 12 Sep 2013 23:18:37 -0500
From: &lt;tv100@tv100.com&gt;
Return-Path: &lt;tv100@tv100.com&gt;
Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Reset_your_password?=
Reply-To: &quot;tv100@tv100.com&quot; &lt;tv100@tv100.com&gt;
X-Sender: tv100@tv100.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: &lt;5232921db117e@tv100.com&gt;
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

please someone tell me whats wrong with this...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library this might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is here:

```
to: 501 <>: missing or malformed local part
</pre>The following SMTP error was encountered: 501 <>: missing or malformed local part
<br /><pre>data: 503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:
503-501 <>: missing or malformed local part
503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA
</pre>The following SMTP error was encountered: 503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:
503-501 <>: missing or malformed local part
503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA
```

It looks like your "To" address isn't set to a valid email address. Check that the value of `$address` actually has an email address as used in this line:

```
$this->email->to($address);
```

I'd also check all your other variables (`$from`, `$subject` etc) have valid values.