# Trouble sending email in CodeIgniter via Gmail SMTP

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl, smtp, gmail

I am trying to use Gmail SMTP server to send email from my application built with CodeIgniter but had no luck. I used my Gmail account as the user, but I am changing the config here for confidentiality. I used the code below

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'mypassword';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';


//load email library
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$message = "Please validate your registration using this link: $link.";
$this->email->to($email);
$this->email->from('myemail@gmail.com', 'John Doe');
$this->email->subject('Validate Your Registration');
$this->email->message($message);
if($this->email->send())
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect(base_url()."thanks/indi/$id");
}
else
{
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```

Here are the 2 error messages that appear everytime:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at
>   "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com" port 465, verify your "SMTP" and
>   "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 1553
>
> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be
>   configured to send mail using this method.
>
> From: "John Doe"  Return-Path: 
>   Reply-To: "myemail@gmail.com"  X-Sender:
>   myemail@gmail.com X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
>   Message-ID: <52333cd2aa4fb@gmail.com> Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type:
>   text/plain; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>   =?utf-8?Q?Validate_Your_Registration?= Please validate your registration using this link:
>   http://mywebsite.com/registration/index.php/validate/32/1afa34a7f984eeabdbb0a7d494132ee5.

I tried **587** as port, **ssl://smtp.googlemail.com** as host, and tried different combinations to try if it will work. I tried the usual array constructor to declare the config array as well (e.g. $config = array('protocol' => 'smtp', ...) / $config = Array('protocol' => 'smtp', ...) ). I even tried putting the port inside single quotes, and added an smtp_timeout in the config.

Also, I set my php.ini according to what this page says: http://adisembiring.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/sending-gmail-email-using-codeigniter/
The **extension=php_openssl.dll** is uncommented, but I can't find this line: **extension=php_smtp.dll** which was mentioned in the site above so I just set the **[mail function]** part to something like this

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = ssl://smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 465
```

What should I do to get this working? Any ideas on where I was lacking or something? Thanks. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending email with gmail smtp with codeigniter email library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 2 step verification, have you generated an application specific password?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `$config` array:

```
$config['starttls'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Also if you cannot find `extension=php_smtp.dll` then just add that line in and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Pretty sure it won't coz php_smtp.dll isn't even on the ext folder of my php installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

Change your $config array as following

```
$config['smtp_host']  = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
```