# how i send Email from codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**i using this code to send testing email, but i always facing error, what should i have to do ?**

```
//==========code======================

$config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'localhost',
        'smtp_port' => 25,

        'smtp_user' => 'root',

        'smtp_pass' => '', 

        'mailtype' => 'html',

        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
        'wordwrap' => TRUE
);

$message = ' hello world';
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('xxxxx@live.com'); 
$this->email->to('xxxxx@live.com');
$this->email->subject('Resume from JobsBuddy for your Job posting');
$this->email->message($message);
if($this->email->send())
{
        echo 'Email sent.';
}
else
{
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```

Error from CodeIgniter:

```
 An Error Was Encountered


    The following SMTP error was encountered: 10061 No connection could be made because 

    the target machine actively refused it. 




    Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
    Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 


    Unable to send data: MAIL FROM:


    from: 
    The following SMTP error was encountered: 
    Unable to send data: RCPT TO:
    to: 
    The following SMTP error was encountered: 
    Unable to send data: DATA
    data: 
    The following SMTP error was encountered: 
    Unable to send data: User-Agent: CodeIgniter Date: Wed, 6 Nov 2013 13:50:31 +0000 From: Return-Path: To: xxxx@live.com Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Resume_from_JobsBuddy_for_your_Job_posting?= Reply-To: "xxxx@live.com" X-Sender: 


xxx@live.com X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3 (Normal) Message-ID: 


<527a492796d84@live.com> Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_527a492796d84" This is a multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application may not support this format. --B_ALT_527a492796d84 Content-Type: text/plain; 


charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit hello world --B_ALT_527a492796d84 Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable hello world --B_ALT_527a492796d84--
        Unable to send data: .

        The following SMTP error was encountered: 
        Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

    User-Agent: CodeIgniter


    Date: Wed, 6 Nov 2013 13:50:31 +0000
    From: 


    Return-Path: 
    To: xxx@live.com


    Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?Resume_from_JobsBuddy_for_your_Job_posting?=
    Reply-To: "xxx@live.com" 
    X-Sender: xxx@live.com
    X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
    X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
    Message-ID: <527a492796d84@live.com>
    Mime-Version: 1.0


    Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_527a492796d84"

    This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
    Your email application may not support this format.



    --B_ALT_527a492796d84


    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1


    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

    hello world


    --B_ALT_527a492796d84
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1


    Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

     hello world

    --B_ALT_527a492796d84--
```

Comment: Do you have SMTP service in your server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
>       Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: ---- Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

1. Make sure that the SMPT parameters are correct
2. Make sure that your server has SMTP service running

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your server is not allowing `root` user to login to the SMTP server (never use root as your user).

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch21_:_Configuring_Linux_Mail_Servers) on how to setup SMTP, or alternatively, use another provider like [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) or [GMail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1622996/1415625) to send e-mail with. It will increase the odds that your mail will not be marked as spam.

Answer (score -2):

```
Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: Unable to send email using PHP SMTP.
```

Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

1.Make sure that the SMPT parameters are correct

2.Make sure that your server has SMTP service running