# After PC restart I can't send mail through local host any more

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have just discovered that I am no longer able to send mails through my local host(MAMP) with CodeIgnier. I haven't change the configs, the only thing that really happened was system restart. Below are the reported error and my config, any help is appreciated.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: 
1: fsockopen(): SSL: crypto enabling timeout
2: fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto
3: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Unknown error)
4: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
5: fgets() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
6: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
5 & 6 are repeated multiple times
Filename: libraries/Email.php
```

**Mail Config**

```
$config = Array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
'smtp_port' => 465,
'smtp_user' => 'mymail@gmail.com',
'smtp_pass' => 'my_password',
'mailtype' => 'html',
'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
'wordwrap' => TRUE);
```

**Mail sending**

```
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
$this->email->from('mymail@gmail.com'); 
$this->email->to('mymail@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('Test subject');
$this->email->message($message);
```

Comment: Any firewall settings on your machine that have been changed, but not saved, before the reboot?

Comment: Do you have php_openssl php extension enabled ? If not then enable it and try to execute script again.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm nothing that wasn't here before. I am on a macbook

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution it has to be enabled since it worked before, I don't even remember allowing it.. But I can access my local host as `http://localhost/controller` that means the ssl works right?

Comment: check your php.ini file and look for extension=php_openssl.dll if you have ";" please remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Do try following

```
 $config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

// Set to, from, message, etc.

$result = $this->email->send();
```

and Find out more details here [Sending email with gmail smtp with codeigniter email library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library)