# Accept email address from user and send email to that address

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

```
public function send_mail() {

    $this->email->from('your@email.com', 'My Name');
    $this->email->to('to@email.com');
    $this->email->cc('cc@email.com');


    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

    $this->email->send();

    echo $this->email->print_debugger();

}
```

i'm trying out the codeigniter email func but i cant seem to receive the test mail, but it saids that it has successfully send the mail but there's none,
new to ci so i'm confused about this problem, $this->load->library('email'); is also loaded,
anyhelp thanks!

## EDIT

ok guys thanks for the answer i have added the ff code and it now works,

```
$config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'your email',
            'smtp_pass' =>  'your password'
            );
```

Now my question is how will I edit the codes above to accept the "to" email from the user?

okay i did the "to" part already, and its like this

```
$this->email->to($point->email);
```

need help again with the "message" part, i need to put data from the user in the "message" part, i tried what i did in the "to" part but it only accepts one item, i need multiple items, thanks

Comment: what to the mail server logs say?

Comment: from local server or hosting? If hosting, what is your host?

Comment: its from a localhost,

Comment: ahm thanks for the answer guys i had it running already by adding protocols now my question is how will a edit the code above to accept the "to" email from the user? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in my linux server without any $config.

Please **[read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library)** to set another protocol

Answer (score 0):

In the section where you're calling the function `send_mail()`, pass the email address and other data as well, as arguments to the function; something like this:

```
$to = $point->email;
$msg = $point->message; // the message part
$phone = $point->phone; // phone number
$address = $point->address; // postal address
$this->send_email($to, $msg, $phone, $address);
```

And then slightly modify the `send_mail()` function as:

```
// $to_address will contain the value stored in $to, i.e. "abc@def.com" in this case
public function send_mail($to_address, $body_message, $phone_no, $addr) {

    // can make use of extra data like phone number, address in here
    $this->email->from('your@email.com', 'My Name');
    $this->email->to($to_address);
    $this->email->message($body_message);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: thanks for this bec of your comment i had an idea and it worked thanks

Comment: I assume you started passing multiple arguments?

Comment: Updated my answer to accommodate the message part as well as other extra information

Comment: sorry for this question, but ahm what will be the "$this->email->message" of phone number and address?