# Send e-mail with Codeigniter 3.0.3 via SMTP

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ubuntu, smtp

My `email.php` located within `config/` folder:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'gmfernandes@[domain].com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = '[password]';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

My `email()` method:

```
public function email()
{
    $from_name = $this->input->post('nome_email');
    $from_email = $this->input->post('email_email');
    $to = 'gmfernandes@[domain].com';
    $subject = 'Testing';
    $message = $this->input->post('proposta_email');

    $this->email->from($from_email, $from_name);
    $this->email->to($to);
    $this->email->subject($subject);
    $this->email->message($message);

    if ($this->email->send()) {
        echo 'Sent!';
    } else {
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }

    die;
}
```

My `autoload.php`:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'form_validation', 'email');
```

I am trying to make this work. I have spent hours looking for a solution but NONE of them helped me. Removed and installed `sendmail` and `postfix` several times, tried to use default configuration but nothing. It doesn't work with me.

Now, the message that is shown:

```
hello: F

The following SMTP error was encountered: F
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Mon, 11 Jan 2016 18:11:54 -0200
From: "Gabriel" <mfgabriel@[domain].com>
Return-Path: <mfgabriel@[domain].com>
To: gmfernandes@[domain].com
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?Testing?=
Reply-To: "mfgabriel@[domain].com" <mfgabriel@[domain].com>
X-Sender: mfgabriel@[domain].com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <56940c8a3846e@[domain].com>
Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_56940c8a384c8"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_56940c8a384c8
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Teste


--B_ALT_56940c8a384c8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Teste

--B_ALT_56940c8a384c8--
```

What to do?

**Edit #1**

After chaning my `config.php` file to `ssl://smtp.gmail.com`, a new and bigger error message has shown. Above the `User Agent: CodeIgniter`:

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP g130sm55276890qkb.28 - gsmtp

hello: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2804:14d:2c81:17a2:f82f:e7e9:68ec:6230]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8

Failed to authenticate password. Error: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 g130sm55276890qkb.28 - gsmtp
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

Comment: @GabrieIMF as in my answer try with `ssl://smtp.googlemail.com`

Answer (score 1):

You use the port 465, which means SSL.

```
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Email()
{
        parent::Controller();   
            $this->load->library('email');
}

function index()
{
    $config['protocol']    = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_port']    = '465';
    $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
    $config['smtp_user']    = 'mygmail@gmail.com';
    $config['smtp_pass']    = '*******';
    $config['charset']    = 'utf-8';
    $config['newline']    = "\r\n";
    $config['mailtype'] = 'text'; // or html
    $config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not      

    $this->email->initialize($config);


    $this->email->from('mygmail@gmail.com', 'myname');
    $this->email->to('target@gmail.com'); 

    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  

    $this->email->send();

    echo $this->email->print_debugger();

     $this->load->view('email_view');

   }
```

Check forum: [Sending email with gmail smtp with codeigniter email library](https://expressionengine.com/forums/archive/topic/132443/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library)

Check this answer: [Sending email Codeigniter Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024117/sending-email-codeigniter-error#answer-28024235)

Answer (score 0):

Done. It worked. I had to allow access from less secure apps in My Account > Sign-in & security configurations and do as Schellingerht said.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `ssl://smtp.googlemail.com` instead of `smtp.gmail.com`

```
$config = array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);

$this->load->library('email', $config);

$this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$this->email->to('someone@example.com');

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

$this->email->send();
```