# Email Class : Codeigniter 3.0,Cant Send Email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I have Been try to send Mail using Codeigniter 3.0 .

My Controller :

```
function index()
    {

              $ci = get_instance();
                $ci->load->library('email');
                $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
                $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
                $config['smtp_port'] = "465";
                $config['smtp_user'] = "sriramarvind95@gmail.com";
                $config['smtp_pass'] = "";
                $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
                $config['mailtype'] = "html";
                $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

                $ci->email->initialize($config);
                $ci->email->from('sriramarvind95@gmail.com', 'Blabla');
                $list = array('skarthikeyan1410@gmail.com');
                $ci->email->to($list);
                $this->email->reply_to('sriramarvind95@gmail.com', 'Explendid Videos');
                $ci->email->subject('This is an email test');
                $ci->email->message('It is working. Great!');
                $result=$ci->email->send();

                if($result){
                    $data['email']="sent";
                }
                else{
                    $data['email']="not Sent";
                }
        //echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
```

my view

```
<?php
if ($email="not Sent"){
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
else{
    echo "Sent";
}
```

?>

Other than this,i configured my gmail account to allow less apps to login into gmail.

yet i get this error :

> 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP p10sm8628622obk.11 - gsmtp  hello: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [23.102.172.97] 250-SIZE 35882577
>   250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
>   OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING
>   250 SMTPUTF8 Failed to authenticate password. Error: 534-5.7.14 Please
>   log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14
>   Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754
>   p10sm8628622obk.11 - gsmtp  Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your
>   server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
>   User-Agent: CodeIgniter Date: Mon, 11 Apr 2016 13:17:26 -0700 From:
>   "Blabla"  Return-Path:
>    To: skarthikeyan1410@gmail.com Reply-To:
>   "Explendid Videos"  Subject:
>   =?utf-8?Q?=54=68=69=73=20=69=73=20=61=6E=20=65=6D=61=69=6C=20=74=65=73=74?= X-Sender: sriramarvind95@gmail.com X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3
>   (Normal) Message-ID: <570c06564edde@gmail.com> Mime-Version: 1.0
>
> Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_570c06564edf2"
>
> This is a multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application
>   may not support this format.
>
> --B_ALT_570c06564edf2 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>
> It is working. Great!
>
> --B_ALT_570c06564edf2 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
>
> It is working. Great=21
>
> --B_ALT_570c06564edf2--

Trying this is in hosted service , not in localhost.

i have no clue , i use plain text in my password field . is it correct or should i generate something.

Please help.

Comment: Change smtp_host to 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com'. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library

Comment: not working, i tried all , it says the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Change these

```
$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com"; # Change
$config['smtp_port'] = "465";
$config['smtp_user'] = "sriramarvind95@gmail.com";
$config['smtp_pass'] = ""; # Your account password
```