# CI Sending Mail using SMTP

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm going straight to the point here.
I'm trying to send an mail using codeigniter library.
However, I'm not receiving any email and there are no errors shown on my code.
I don't know why it doesn't work.

I've also followed the `2 step verification` and `allow access to less secure apps`

However when I omit the config, it send me an email which goes directly to the spam section. I don't know why it goes to spam section.

Here's my code:

```
public function sending_email(){

    // The mail sending protocol.
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    // SMTP Server Address for Gmail.
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
    // SMTP Port - the port that you is required
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
    // SMTP Username like. (abc@gmail.com)
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'sample@gmail.com';
    // SMTP Password like (abc***##)
    $config['smtp_pass'] = '****';
    // Load email library and passing configured values to email library
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    // Sender email address
    $this->email->from('sample@gmail.com', 'sample');
    // Receiver email address.for single email
    $this->email->to('receiver@gmail.com');
    //send multiple email
    //$this->email->to(abc@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com,jkl@gmail.com);
    // Subject of email
    $this->email->subject('test');
    // Message in email
    $this->email->message('hello world!');
    // It returns boolean TRUE or FALSE based on success or failure
    echo $this->email->send(); 

}
```

Comment: I think the smtp server should be `smtp.gmail.com` https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en and if you are using 2 step verification you should be using an app specific password https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @Morfinismo does not work at all. tried what you suggested..

Comment: I recommend looking into the answers provided on this question which seems like a duplicate of yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code also if commented link's answer is not working.

```
$config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => 465,
        'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
        'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
        'mailtype'  => 'html', 
        'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
    );
    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    // Set to, from, message, etc.

    $result = $this->email->send();
```