# Codeigniter SMTP error with email

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I Have configured the email setting in codeigniter

```
 $config = array(
 'protocol' => 'smtp',
 'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
 'smtp_timeout'=>30,
 'smtp_port' => 465,
 'smtp_user' => 'XXXXX@gmail.com',
 'smtp_pass' => 'XXXXX',
 'charset'=>'utf-8',    
 'mailtype' => 'html',
 'newline'=>'\r\n'
);
```

I have also uncomment in php.ini is

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

But still now i am getting error is

```
  A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2063

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\rtd-admin\application\modules\message\controllers\Message.php
Line: 26
Function: send

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\rtd-admin\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

and second error is

```
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
```

Comment: I googled your error code, and there is another question here on SO about the same problem, have a look at some of the answers there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. And more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more)

Comment: Please try adding `"smtp_crypto"=>"tsl"` or `"smtp_crypto"=>"ssl"` , In addition look at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library`