# Fail to connect Email class in codeigniter with PHP

Tags: codeigniter

I am sending my code but it gives following error to send email.

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: mail()
>   [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port
>   25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use
>   ini_set() Filename: libraries/Email.php Line Number: 1554

Code is as following.

email.php file is a following.

```
    <?php

    class Email extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->helper('form');
        }

        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('contact');
        }

        public function send()
        {
            $this->load->library('email');

            $name=$this->input->post('name');
            $form=$this->input->post('form');
            $subject=$this->input->post('sub');
            $msg=$this->input->post('message');


            $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
            $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl:/gamil.smtp.com';
            $config['smtp_port'] = 25;
            $config['smtp_user'] ='rameshjadav133@gmail.com';
            $config['smtp_pass'] ='jadav4545';

            $this->load->library('email',$config);

            $this->email->from($form,$name);

            $this->email->to('rameshjadav133@gmail.com');

            $this->email->subject($subject);
            $this->email->message($msg);

            if($this->email->send())
            {

            $data = array('message' =>'Email send success fulll....' ); 
            }
            else
            {
                $data = array('message' => 'Email not send' );
            }
                $this->load->view('contact',$data);
        }
    }

    ?>
```

contact.php file is as following.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Contact form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php


        if(isset($message))
        {
            echo $message;
        }
        echo "<h1>Contact form </h1>";
        echo form_open("email/send");
        echo form_label("Name   :  ");
        echo form_input("name");
        echo "<br>";

        echo form_label("From   :  ");
        echo form_input("from");
        echo "<br>";

        echo form_label("Subject   :   ");
        echo form_input("sub");
        echo "<br>";


        echo form_label("Message");
        $data = array('name' => 'message','rows'=>5,'cols'=>32 );
        echo form_textarea($data);
        echo "<br>";

        echo form_submit('submit','send Email');

        echo form_close();
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library

Comment: Do you have a mail server installed? What is the host you are using

Comment: no  i have  no installed any email server install . and  i use localhost for hosting this service