# Codeigniter email class fails to send email due connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: codeigniter, email

This is the error I'm getting when using the email class with Google smtp settings.

```
Severity: Notice

Message: fwrite(): send of 5 bytes failed with errno=10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2250

Backtrace:
```

this is the email class config at the controller file that I have written to send the message

```
$config = array(
                'protocol'  => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'xxxx@gmail.com',
                'smtp_pass' => 'xxxxx',
                'mailtype'  => 'html',
                'charset'   => 'utf-8'
                );
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library

Comment: change `$config['protocol']     = 'smtp';` to `$config['protocol']     = 'mail';`