# AWS SMTP mail error in CodeIgniter (Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.)

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, email, smtp

Am trying to send Email with AWS SMTP

auth access is passed, and configured everything but still got an error from CI

```
$this->load->library("email");
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['useragent']    = 'ses-smtp-user.20160628-105419'; //origon

$config['protocol']     = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']    = 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'; //origon

$config['smtp_user']    = 'user key ';
$config['smtp_pass']    = 'password';
$config['smtp_port']    = '465';
$config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";      //should be "\r\n"
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";   //should be "\r\n"
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls'; // TLS protocol
$config['email_newline'] = "\r\n"; // SES hangs with just \n

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from("email addr",'name');
$this->email->to("mail to");

$this->email->subject("test email");
$this->email->message("test!"); //메세지
$status = $this->email->send();
if($status) echo "IT WORKED!";
print_r($this->email->print_debugger());
```

am not sure to change 'useragent' value 'CodeIgniter' to 'ses-smtp-user.20160628-105419'

and got the following error using print_debugger() when im running this code

```
hello:
The following SMTP error was encountered:

starttls:
The following SMTP error was encountered:
The following SMTP error was encountered:

Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Date: Wed, 20 Jun 2018 02:23:28 +0000
From: =?UTF-8?Q?=EB=B3=84=EB=AA=85?= <email>
Return-Path: <email>
To: mailto
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?aws=20mail=20test=20mail=20f?==?UTF-8?Q?orm=20ori?= =?UTF-8?Q?gon!=20=20!?=
Reply-To: <email>
User-Agent: ses-smtp-user.20160628-105419
X-Sender: email
X-Mailer: ses-smtp-user.20160628-105419
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <email>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_5b29baa048f13"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_5b29baa048f13
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

test!


--B_ALT_5b29baa048f13
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

test=21

--B_ALT_5b29baa048f13--
```

Comment: have you installed a mail server ?

Comment: installed sendmail but still same!

Comment: using PHPMailer will solve this

Comment: em.... okay. i was trying to use Email libraries in CI. i should take PHPMailer

Comment: Please use CI library to send email

Comment: Please this article https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codeigniter/codeigniter_sending_email.htm

Comment: Duplicate issue **Solution**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library

Comment: @chintansureliya sorry nope. am using tls protocol and not working, even tried that solutions for Gmail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
    'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
// set new line
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

//set to, from, message body, etc.
$result = $this->email->send();
```

Comment: What issue you are getting?

Comment: i setted everything to use email library in CI instead PHPMailer
but doesn't work at all, got an error and it just says `Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.` ahh... makes me go crazy

Comment: i have no idea with this error, but u know what? PHPMailer works well...!

Comment: Please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library

Comment: Change smtp_port from 465 to 587 Make sure $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; is in double quotes not single quotes