# CodeIgniter sending Email using Gmail SMTP

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, smtp, gmail

What I tried:

1. I tried using below config and generated app password
2. I tried also updating the php.ini with below details.

   public function EmailNotifications(){

   ```
            $config = Array(
                          'protocol' => 'smtp',
                          'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                          'validation'=>TRUE,
                          'smtp_timeout'=>30,
                          'smtp_port'=> 465,
                          'smtp_user' => 'sender@gmail.com', // change it to yours
                          'smtp_pass' => 'ualxykfuomcrfsdi', // this is the app password generated
                          'mailtype' => 'html',
                          'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                          'wordwrap' => TRUE
                    );



             $this->load->library('email', $config);
             $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
             $this->email->from('sender@gmail.com','Teradyne Online Shipment'); // change it to yours
             $this->email->to("receiver@gmail.com"); // change it to yours
             $this->email->subject('Account Request');
             $this->email->message($message);

              if($this->email->send())
             {
                redirect('admin/home'); 
             }
             else
            {
             show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
            }
        }
   ```

Error:

[image]

Questions:

1. Do I need to create a Gmail account for Business or just the personal account?
2. Is the configuration different for XAMPP localhost?

Comment: Did you follow the links to their support pages, that are contained in the error message?

Comment: @CBroe Yes, but still could'nt resolve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending email with gmail smtp with codeigniter email library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library)

Comment: @marcogmonteiro - already tried this but still not sending an email