# email varification codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email

I Tried to send email from codeigniter3 but it's showed my this error

The following SMTP error was encountered: 0 php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

I have a file on application/config/email.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config = array(
   'protocol' => 'smtp', // 'mail', 'sendmail', or 'smtp'
    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.example.com', 
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'my email',
    'smtp_pass' => 'pass',
    'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl', //can be 'ssl' or 'tls' for example
    'mailtype' => 'text', //plaintext 'text' mails or 'html'
    'smtp_timeout' => '4', //in seconds
    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
    'wordwrap' => TRUE

);
```

my controller is

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class EmailController extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent:: __construct();

        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('email/contact');
    }

    function send() {
        $this->load->config('email');
        $this->load->library('email');
        
        $from = $this->config->item('smtp_user');
        $to = $this->input->post('to');
        $subject = $this->input->post('subject');
        $message = $this->input->post('message');

        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from($from);
        $this->email->to($to);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
       


        if ($this->email->send()) {
            echo 'Your Email has successfully been sent.';
        } else {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }
    }
}
```

my view is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CodeIgniter Send Email</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h3>Use the form below to send email</h3>
            <form method="post" action="<?=base_url('email')?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="email" id="to" name="to" placeholder="Receiver Email">
                <br><br>
                <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                <br><br>
                <textarea rows="6" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Type your message here"></textarea>
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Send Email" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: take a look here if you want to send a email with smtp [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555145/sending-email-with-gmail-smtp-with-codeigniter-email-library) or change the provider to simple **mail**